# How to change PDF view background color in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on Flutter project and I'm trying to change the PDF view background color to white but some reason the color is not apply even when I wrap with other widget so I would be really appreciated If I can get any help or suggestion.

Basically I want this to be white too. I'm not sure it's possible but it would be awesome if I can get any suggestion.

[image]

```
      body: SfPdfViewer.asset(
        'assets/data/songs.pdf',
        initialZoomLevel: 3.0,
        enableDoubleTapZooming: true,
        initialScrollOffset: Offset.fromDirection(10),
        controller: _pdfViewerController,
        pageLayoutMode: PdfPageLayoutMode.single,
        pageSpacing: 4,
        canShowScrollHead: false,
        onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
          _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(widget.pageNumber);
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit late but to make it easy for anyone in the future here is how to do it:

first you need to add this to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
syncfusion_flutter_core: ^20.4.53
```

then import this:

```
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_core/theme.dart';
```

**and finally** wrap your `SfPdfViewer.asset()` widget with a `SfPdfViewerTheme()`:

```
SfPdfViewerTheme(
              
     data: SfPdfViewerThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple, //<----
     ),
              
     child: SfPdfViewer.asset(
          //your code here ...
     ),
 ),
```

for more information [check this](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/175179/is-there-a-way-to-make-visual-customizations-for-widgets-in-a-sfpdfviewer).

Answer (score 1):

```
final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text('Syncfusion Flutter PdfViewer'),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons. bookmark,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        _pdfViewerKey.currentState?.openBookmarkView();
      },
    ),
  ],
),
body: SfPdfViewer.network(
  'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
  key: _pdfViewerKey,
),
);
}
```

**you can use scaffold widget and give background color**
[more information](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer)

Comment: I added background color in Scaffold widget  and it's still not working.

Comment: I think it's not working because it's not a scaffold background and it's PDF background but still not sure about the solution.